# I have this type of getStringArrayListExtra but how to get exam_ques_id value form it?

Tags: android, android-studio

```
arr_ques_arr = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("qustion_arr");
```

LOGLIST :

```
[{"user_exam":[{"exam_ques_id":"82","exam_id":"2","answer":"-1","user_ans":"0"},{"exam_ques_id":"90","exam_id":"2","answer":"-1","user_ans":"2"}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

use JSONObject class to parse the json